# Finding specific eigenvalues

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Given an $n\times n$ matrix $Q$ (with e.g. $n\approx10^4$) I am only interested in the 3rd smallest eigenvalue of $Q,$ and not the entire spectrum (assume all eigenvalues are real, e.g. a Hermitian matrix). So one direct way would be to solve the Eigensystem, order the eigenvalues and pick the 3rd one:

```
{eigv, U} = Eigensystem[Q];
order = Ordering[eigv];
eigv = eigv[[order]];
res = eigv[[3]];
```

1. **(Main question)**: But is there a way to go about this in a more targeted and efficient way considering that we know which eigenvalue we are looking for?
2. In the above I order the eigenvalues, but if we don't, does `Eigensystem` arrange them in a specific order already?

---

Addendum:

The matrix can has only nonnegative eigenvalues ([M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix)), and its first eigenvalue, $\lambda_0,$ is typically $0.$ Therefore, the idea is to find the 3rd smallest eigenvalue $\lambda$ in magnitude, knowing that the real parts of all $\lambda$ are nonnegative. These properties are e.g. satisfied for [Laplacian matrices of graphs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KirchhoffMatrix.html), in this case graphs with $10^4$ nodes.

Comment: Are your eigenvalues guaranteed to be real? If not, what do you mean by smallest?

Comment: @mikado good question, yes let us only consider the case where all eigenvalues are indeed real.

Comment: `Eigensystem[Q, 3, Method -> {"Arnoldi", "Criteria" -> "RealPart"}]`could be one choice.

Comment: Is you matrix numeric and much larger then 3 by 3, or is it a small symbolic matrix?

Comment: @yarchik Sorry for the late reply, no this is asked for large matrices (e.g. $10000 \times 10000$) which are not necessarily sparse either, sorry I forgot to clarify this in the post, great remark!

Comment: Do you mean smallest in magnitude (that is, closest to zero). Or most negative?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau The smallest in magnitude. The matrix is in fact an [M-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-matrix), which means all eigenvalues are non-negative, in particular in my case I know the first eigenvalue is $0$. This is quite similar to [Laplacian matrices](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KirchhoffMatrix.html) of graphs.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest finding the largest eigenvalues (call it `eigbig`) using `Eigenvalues[mat,1]`, then find the three largest in magnitude of `mat-eigbig*identity` and add `eigbig` to them. Can use `Eigensystem` for this second step to get the corresponding eigenvectors.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau this is really neat! If you could kindly post this as answer it'd be definitely useful for future readers as well! Incidentally,I just found out one can call `Eigenvalues` like so `Eigenvalues[mat,-k]` to find the `k` smallest eigenvalues in absolute value. But the latter would only work if we are sure all eigenvalues are nonnegative, but yours work irrespectively, right?

Comment: Correct on the last question. Right now is the annual Wolfram Tech Conference. I'll post a response if I find enough time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what I had suggested in a comment. We will work with a 100x100 symmetric sparse matrix, and make it diagonally dominant (or close enough to that) so that all eigenvalues are positive.

```
rng = 100;
nonzerocount = 3*rng;
SeedRandom[1111]

mat0 = SparseArray[
   Thread[RandomInteger[{1, rng}, {nonzerocount, 2}] -> 
     RandomReal[{0, 1}, nonzerocount]], {rng, rng}];
mat = mat0 + Transpose[mat0] + SparseArray[{a_, a_} -> 5, {rng, rng}];
```

First check the smallest eigenvalues using the method we want to avoid:

```
Eigenvalues[mat, -5]

(* Out[337]= {2.6747750632, 2.43141432273, 2.40432837499, 2.30813913679, \
1.93291151486} *)
```

So these are values we hope to attain without requiring an linear equation solving under the hood.

First get the biggest eigenvalue.

```
eigbig = First[Eigenvalues[mat, 1]]

(* Out[338]= 8.94206162291 *)
```

Now shift by the negative of this largest, and obtain the three most negative eigenvalues, along with their corresponding eigenvectors. Shift back to get the correct eigenvalues, that is, the smallest positive ones from the original matrix.

```
matShifted = mat - SparseArray[{a_, a_} -> eigbig, {rng, rng}];
smallEig = Eigensystem[matShifted, 3];
smallEig[[1]] + eigbig

(* Out[344]= {1.93291151486, 2.30813913679, 2.40432837499} *)
```

We have recovered the ones we wanted.

When I instead use a dimension of 10000 it takes around 0.1 seconds on my desktop to find the largest eigenvalue, and around 0.5 seconds to get those eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors. Finding them using `Eigensystem[mat,-3]`, in contrast, requires 6.8 seconds.

Comment: If I may ask: in using this method for my matrices (which are `KirchhoffMatrix[]` of graphs, I keep getting the warning: `Eigenvalues::maxit2: Warning: maximum number of iterations, 5000, has been reached by the Arnoldi algorithm without convergence to the specified tolerance, but the current best computed value has been returned. You can use method options with Method -> {Arnoldi, opts} to increase the size of basis vectors, the maximum number of iterations, ...`. Should I be worried? from your experience, how should I workaround the convergence problem? Many thanks for any hints!

Comment: I assume this badness happens when you do `Eigenvalues[mat, 1]`. It is not a familiar problem for me. My advice would be to increase the iterations, and maybe also extract the two or three largest eigenvalues to see if they are close to one another (multiplicity or near-multiplicity might account for a convergence issue, I think). Since the eigenvalues are apparently all positive, there might also be tricks to play using `SingularValueList`, again extracting only the top few.

Comment: Good point about closeness of values, maybe it is the case, I'm not sure to be honest. Here are 2 examples of 3 largest eigens: `{3.1433639275971204, 3.0693111881309645, 3.0135000156020246}` and `{3.110447056413233, 3.080469746360026, 2.9917100715725695}.`

Comment: Those values do not strike me as being terribly close. Another possibility occurred to me. You could try working in extended precision. This would slow things substantially but might do a better job of handling the matrix.

Comment: Indeed! Does that mean simply wrapping `Eigenvalues[...]` in `N[]` to enforce machine precision?

Comment: If the input is machine precision, the only way to "raise" it (somewhat artificially) is to use `SetPrecision[... 50]`, say. `N[]` will not change machine precision to bigums.

Comment: It seems for the cases I do get that warning, the values are in the order of $10^{-4}$ to $10^{-6},$ much smaller than I thought at first. I have tried setting precision, it doesn't seem to resolve the problem. Is there an alternative way one could sanity check the so found eigenvalues? (to assess the convergence warning).

Comment: Might try rescaling in case the algorithm is sensitive to that (it might be, I'm not sure). I'd start with multiplying the matrix  in question by 10^5, say.

Answer (score 4):

As yarchik says in the comments, you can use the "Arnoldi" method. However, the "Arnoldi" method doesn't work well for finding the smallest real eigenvalues (perhaps a bug), but you can instead find the largest real eigenvalues after changing the sign of the matrix. Here is an example Hermitian matrix (so eigenvalues are real):

```
SeedRandom[1];
m = (ConjugateTranspose[#] + #)& @ RandomComplex[10+10I, {10, 10}];
```

Finding the full eigenvalues (I use [`Eigenvalues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigenvalues), but [`Eigensystem`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Eigensystem) works similarly):

```
Eigenvalues[m] //ReverseSort
```

> {98.0228, 23.1452, 18.0616, 12.4434, 8.72238, -0.890917, -9.86992, -13.0016, \
>   -20.4409, -26.7991}

Now, using the "Arnoldi" method:

```
-Eigenvalues[-m, {3}, Method->{"Arnoldi", "Criteria"->"RealPart"}]
```

> {-13.0016}