# How to get single $n^{th}$ eigenvalue and eigenfunction using NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I am trying to solve the Schrödinger equation for a $2D$ Harmonic Oscillator using the following codes.

### Code-1

```
  L = 10.0;
    V[x_, y_] = (x^2 + y^2)*0.5;
    {vals, funs} = 
     NDEigensystem[{(-1/2)Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + V[x, y]*u[x, y], 
       DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
      u[x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 20000, 
      Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" ->{"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}},
  "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", MaxIterations -> Infinity}}]
```

However, due to computational limitations, the system gets hanged while calculating $20000$ eigenvalues and eigenfunctions using the above code although it works perfectly.

### Code-2

```
L = 10.0;
V[x_, y_] = (x^2 + y^2)*0.5;
{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{(-1/2)Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] + V[x, y]*u[x, y], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, -L, L}, {y, -L, L}, 1, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions"-> {"MaxCellMeasure"-> 0.01}}},
    "Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST", "Interval" -> {0, 3}}}]
```

Using the above code, I can find an eigenvalue and the corresponding eigenfunction within an energy band.

I aim to find $ n^{th} $ eigenvalue and corresponding eigenfunction without setting a limit for the energy band as my system could not handle large amounts of data.

or is there any other way to find a large number of eigenvalues?

Comment: Is is true that you want to find the $n$-th _smallest_ eigenvalue? Have you seen for example: [Finding specific eigenvalues](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/208564/finding-specific-eigenvalues)?

Comment: How about finding all eigenvalues and selecting the n-th one?

Comment: It's difficult to find 20000 eigenvalues on a system with $14GB$ RAM.

Comment: In this case, the Schroedinger equation is exactly solvable. So, why don't you use the exact solutions?  Either polar or Cartesian coordinates are suitable to find the exact spectrum.

Comment: Are you suggesting to do the symbolic evaluation rather than numericic evaluation? Here, in this particular problem it's fine to do the symbolic calculation and get the desired result from the general solution. However, with the actual problem I'm having, it is not so easy to find a general solution.